# Can an iOS static library contain classes/interfaces, that can be used/implemented by iOS code that is using the library?

Tags: ios, macos, static-libraries, ios-frameworks

I apologize if this is a dumb question, or if it does not make sense. I've written some Objective-C code before, but I am not very familiar with writing code for OS X or iOS; I'm pretty much a novice. Currently, I'm trying to port a project from OS X into iOS. The project compiles into a Framework, that other OS X projects can use.

I'm trying to do something similar for iOS. I understand that iOS does not support Frameworks that contain `dylib`s and that the solution is to create a static library. However, the OS X Framework has several classes (in `.m` files) that the implementing code uses, extends, or implements. All the examples I've seen for static libraries seem to define a header-file with some functions that can be compiled into a static library.

Is it possible to have classes inside the static library, that iOS code can use? Also, how can I tell if the code is using dynamic libraries?

Comment: Your assertions are not entirely true. iOS Does support frameworks, they just cannot contain `dylib`s. Very important distinction there.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII Thanks for the clarification! Like I said, I'm a novice. How can I tell if the code i'm porting uses dynamic libraries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, static libraries can contain Objective-C classes.

In some cases, you will need to pass options to the linker to force it to include all of the classes and categories defined in a static library.  See http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1490/_index.html

Comment: Richard commented on my question and said that I cannot convert the project over if it contains dynamic libraries. I know that the project uses third-party libraries. Are those considered dynamic libraries?

Comment: You won't be able to use any OS X libraries, dynamic or static, on iOS.  You will need iOS versions of those libraries, and if the third-party vendors don't supply them, and their source code is not available, then you can't use them.